# Which accompanying text do you suggest on these topics of finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Please take a look at pages 80-85 (Section 2.6 Finite fields) of this handbook, [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).

I am trying to learn the mathematics enumerated in these pages.  I do *not* need the algorithms. I will also skip any proof of theorems. The learning is for background reading as preparation for the field of cryptography that use them.

While the handbook is an excellent one and authoritative, it is somewhat concise for my purpose. It states the theories and facts without explaining the intuition behind one. Also, it does not contain many examples. This is quite natural, this is a handbook, not a textbook. I am looking for one or two texts or lecture notes dealing more or less in these areas but with elaborations and lots of examples to facilitate self-learning.

Page 86 of the same handbook suggests four references ([[646]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3411161116), [[764]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521065674), [[830]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898381916), [[841]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0792392825)) for further reading. I have taken a look at all of these except the first one. But these are too elaborate for the time I can spend on these topics.

I have done a thorough search over the Internet, without much success. Perhaps lack of knowledge on my part 
is also working as an impediment.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I would search queries like `finite fields introduction pdf`. Some good notes are bound to turn up. At least compared to abstract algebra / field theory / galois theory at large, the topic of finite fields shouldn't need a whole book in print to fulfill backgrounding reading as preparation for learning about algorithms or cryptography that use them (which is what I assume you want the background for).

Comment: If you have access to a university library, go look at the intro abstract algebra textbooks; many of them will have a chapter or two on finite fields.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Applied Abstract Algebra by Lidl and Pilz](http://books.google.fi/books/about/Applied_Abstract_Algebra.html?id=i17KR1dhTTAC&redir_esc=y). It does not go nearly to the same depth as the definite tome *Finite Fields* by Lidl & Niederreiter that you already looked at. I gather that you are largely interested in applications, so this book might fit the bill. I have occasionally perused it, and it looks ok. My F.F. needs are more comprehensive, so I am won't fully endorse it, but I have used it occasionally.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot. Looks like a good one. This will help me a lot in my self learning process. At brief first glance had a feeling that it wants to open your eyes to intuitive learning which I am looking for.

Comment: @anon The first one returned in the list, [the course chapter at MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/lecture-notes/chap7.pdf) turned out to be a very good one. I have to read less that thirty pages and I have a feeling that I have began to understand the things. The accompanying videos are definite plus. Previously, I was looking at the returned flood of search results without any comprehension. You have shown  me the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtually any book on algebra will contain more, but since you are especially interested in coding theory, I can recommend this [coding theory book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824704657) which is a little less terse (see pages 111-115).

Here's another [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/lecture-notes/chap7.pdf) do a document with worked out examples. It looks like it is written for engineers (but I'm not sure if that's a plus or minus for you).

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html) has a short article with a worked example. In this case, [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_fields) might be fairly helpful, because it appears to contain a *lot* of examples! Be on your guard for typos, of course.

---

Searching "finite field pdf" turned up lots of relevant hits, including [this](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/finflds.pdf) slideshow on the topic.

The main theory of finite fields is very simple. A finite field has prime characteristic $p$ for some $p$, and then it must be of order $p^k$ for some positive integer $k$. There are finite fields of all possible orders $p^k$ for each combination of prime $p$ and positive integer $k$.

Finally, the group of nonzero elements in the field must be cyclic, and so there are things called *primitive elements* which generate that group.

Constructing the fields of prime order is easy: they are exactly $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. The link I provided above furnishes the last task by giving some worked out examples of how the rest of the fields can be constructed with a quotient $\Bbb F_{p^k}=\Bbb F_p[x]/(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb F_p$ of degree $k$.

One more thing that comes to mind for coding theory is the "Freshman's Dream Theorem" that for any polynomial $g(x)$ over $\Bbb F_{p^k}$, $g(x^p)=(g(x))^p$ which sometimes comes in handy. For example, $(x+2)^3=x^3+2^3=x+2$ over the field $\Bbb F_3$.

There are probably some finer details about fields that I'm not mentioning, but the above facts were sufficient for a few years of graduate study on coding theory in my case, anyhow.

Comment: [The course chapter at MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/lecture-notes/chap7.pdf) turned out to be a very good one. I have to read less that thirty pages and I have a feeling that I have began to understand the things. The accompanying videos are definite plus. Previously, I was looking at the returned flood of search results without any comprehension. Examples in the book you mentioned are very helpful. Yet to take a look at the slides.